# Api restful con curl php

Tags: php, api, curl

Estoy tratando de consumir una Api restFul, tengo el sig. Codigo:

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init("http://187.167.69.219:8080/ListaPrecios/rest/DPConsultaCliente?ClienteId=71039");//mi url/direccion
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result; //imprimo
?>
```

[image: Imagen de RestEasy]

He hecho pruebas en la extension de Chrome RestEasy y si me devuelve los datos...alguien podría ayudarme?
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ya lo edité....

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código y [funciona lo mas bien](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xJ9v.png). ¿Revisaste los logs de tu Apache?

Comment: Si existe un problema con Apache, podes verlos en `Metrics > Errors`, si existe un problema con `PHP` asegurate de tener activo el `error_log` el cual podes ver usando `Files > File Manager`

Comment: No he encontrado los errores...solamente los logs de conexiones y eso

Comment: los logs de conexiones y demás, son los que debes verificar para darte cuenta que falla. Es la manera en que el servidor te dice que ha fallado. ¿Que te muestran?

Comment: he intentado en 3 servidores lo mismo y nada  :/

Comment: al cargar la página .php no se muestra ningún error?

Comment: ninguno, pensé que era por http, pero intenté con https y tampoco responde, solo se queda en blanco

Answer (score 1):

El código que dejas funciona correctamente, verifica que tengas habilitada la extensión `php_curl` y si no te envía algún error también activa `display_errors=On`, ambos en el php.ini y reinicia el servidor web

Comment: de hecho, me funcionaba y de pronto nada, el display_errors= (ya esta en ON),    como habilito la extensión php_curl? (lo raro es que tampoco con  file_get_contents me imprime nada)

Comment: En el php.in busca `;extension=php_curl.dll` y quita el `;` del inicio y reinicia el servidor web

Comment: ya lo h e realizado y tampoco...me comentas que el codigo que deje funciona?

Comment: Si funciona el código que dejaste, lo copie y ejecute y sin problemas me imprime la información. Como te comento revisa que tengas la extensión habilitada.

`<?php
 phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
?>`

Comment: una ultima pregunta...lo ejecutaste en servidor local?

Comment: En servidor local y para corroborar en hosting ambos sin problemas

Comment: okay duda aclarada, ya que en local me funciona, pero lo he porbado en 3 hostings y nada

Comment: Advertencia : file_get_contents (http://187.167.69.219:8080/ListaPrecios/rest/DPConsultaCliente?ClienteId=71039): no se pudo abrir la secuencia                                    Conexión rechazada        [error en la linea donde esta la URL]  
                                                                                              
                               (he configurado todo de nuevo y me aprece este msj)

Comment: No tendrás algunas restricción de conectividad, porque con file_get_contents debe hacerlo bien ya que no necesita permisos especiales o algunas librería

Comment: ya cambie toda la conf...del php.ini y nop ( lo raro es que solo me pasa con esta url) he intentado con muchas otras y sin problema

Comment: Te muestro la prueba en mi [hosting](https://codigospro.mx/prueba_ws.php)
Abajo esta el código que estoy usando para imprimir eso

Comment: que debo checar en =>    phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);                                                                  ya que me sale una pagina con mucha información